# Dudeney Number program does not show error when int is equated to double

Tags: java, types, comparison

I wrote a simple program in java for finding out whether a number is a dudeney number or not :

```java
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class dudeney_number
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ") ;
        int n = sc.nextInt() ;
        int temp = n ;
        int sum = 0 ;
        while(temp!=0)
        {
            sum+=temp%10 ;
            temp/=10 ;
        }
        
        if(sum==Math.cbrt(n))
        {
            System.out.println("Dudeney number") ;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a dudeney number") ;
        }
    }
}
```

I create a Scanner object (`sc`), input a number from the user (`n`) and find out the sum of the digits in the entered number (`sum`). I then check for equality between the sum of the digits and the cube root of the number entered using `Math.cbrt(n)` . 

`sum` is an integer value with datatype `int` .  `Math.cbrt(n)` returns a `double` value. 
Why does the compiler not return an error when a *32-bit* and a *64-bit* value is compared ?

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: if the value of the 64-bit datatype value is larger than the limit of the 32-bit datatype value, then comparison should not be possible...

Comment: Why not?  Can't you just tell the 64-bit value is bigger without actually even knowing what the 32-bit value is?

Comment: What answer do you expect other than "Because the JLS doesn't say that it should"?

Comment: @ScottHunter but it equalises for some values like 512

Comment: @Sören Then consider my question as "Why does the JLS not say that it should ?"

Comment: Because no on wrote it in there. Unless one of the authors of the JLS pitches in, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @SuperCoder Java is smart and it is performing type coercion behind the scene. This makes all sorts of comparisons possible, e.g. `int` to `long`, `byte` to `float` etc.

Comment: @Shovel_Knight so it typecasts to a similar datatype. What datatype is it typecasting both of the variables to ? `int` or `long` ?

Comment: @SuperCoder not every `double` can be converted into a valid `int`, but every `int` can be converted into a valid `double`, so I would assume that in your case Java is casting `int` to `double` before actually comparing them.

Comment: Under JLS 15.21.1 "Numerical equality operators", "...binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands" (5.6) - this leads to "widening primitive conversion" which states "If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.".